# css trapeze with special layout

Tags: css, shapes

i have to create style for input in such way.

[trapeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYFsj.png)

The problem is that this is not correct trapeze as each side has rotation.
default css3 shapes didn't help me.

Comment: i can create just correct trapeze as here http://prntscr.com/b1010n

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069723/how-to-transform-each-side-of-a-shape-separately/29821407#29821407 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958450/div-slanted-in-2-directions/30520927#30520927

Comment: Thank you! First link helped me.